# Java insert sheet at beggining excel apache poi

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I was wondering if I can insert a sheet and place it at the beginning of my workbook using java poi apache

Comment: workbook.setSheetOrder("SheetName",0);

Answer (score 2):

In current version `apache poi 4.1.0` [Workbook.setSheetOrder](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setSheetOrder-java.lang.String-int-) provides what you wants.

Complete example:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class ExcelInsertSheet {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  String fileName = "Excel.xlsx"; 
  String filePath = "./"; 

  Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath + fileName));

  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("New Sheet");

  workbook.setSheetOrder("New Sheet", 0);
  workbook.setSelectedTab(0);
  workbook.setActiveSheet(0);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(filePath + "Changed" + fileName);
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();
 }

}
```